# intersect two lists of words in python

Tags: python, list

i want to find the intersection of two lists in python. i have something that looks like this:

```
>>> q = ['apple', 'peach', 'pear', 'watermelon', 'strawberry']
>>> w = ['pineapple', 'peach', 'watermelon', 'kiwi']
```

and i want to find something that looks like this:

```
t = ['peach', 'watermelon']
```

i know its a simple, question but im new to python--does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The intersection() method is available for [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set), which can be easily made from lists.

ETA: if you want a list out of it...

```
q = ['apple', 'peach', 'pear', 'watermelon', 'strawberry']
w = ['pineapple', 'peach', 'watermelon', 'kiwi']
t = list(set(q) & set(w))
```

Now t is:

```
['watermelon', 'peach']
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Sets also work with the binary operators `|` (OR = union), `&` (AND = intersection) and `^` (XOR = in one set but not both), so this would give the answer too: `t = set(q) & set(w)`

Comment: Hah, your comment posted just as my edit did. It's kind of fun trying to type out examples before somebody else adds them.

Comment: perfect! and is it possible to save the intersect list (which i accidentally make into a set) as a csv file? @lazyr @Hydrangea

Comment: Use `writer` from the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module and call the `writerow` method of the resulting object (say you call it `mywriter`), like this: `mywriter.writerow(list(set(q) & set(w)))`. The items of each row are written to the file in undefined order.

Comment: @user808545.  Yes, google for `python csv` and click the first link.

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way of doing it is via [set intersection](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
list(set(q) & set(w))
```

If the lists are short, a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) should work.

```
t = [x for x in q if x in w]
```

However, beware, this is `O(n^2)`, so it is not very efficient with long lists.

Comment: The list comprehension solution has quadratic complexity: `lq * lw = O(n^2)` whereas the set operation is linear `2lq + lw = O(n)` with `lq` and `lw` the length of the `q` and `w` lists respectively.

Comment: Because of the list comprehension based solution.

Answer (score 2):

It was discussed here on SO that [intersection](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#set.intersection) works a bit faster, so you can use:

```
q = ['apple', 'peach', 'pear', 'watermelon', 'strawberry']
w = ['pineapple', 'peach', 'watermelon', 'kiwi']
set(q).intersection(w)
```

Comment: this doesn't actually work, q is converted to individual characters

Comment: @Garglesoap just tried and it works
>>> set(q).intersection(w)
{'watermelon', 'peach'}
>>> set(q)
{'watermelon', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'pear', 'peach'}